# Where clause to include and exclude

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables where I am selecting values and then filtering them so that:

1. `BookId` would be 11 or 12
2. `C.Id` is not 5515, 7582, 7648
3. `C.Id` can be 5967 , but if `D.part` is equal to 8, then do not inlude row which has `C.Id=5967 and D.part = 8`

This is my select:

```
select * from dbo.C c
cross join dbo.D d 
where
c.Id = d.Id 
AND (c.BookId = 11 or c.BookId = 12) -- BookId is 11 or 12
and (c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648) -- 5515, 7582, 7648 (do not include)
or (c.Id = 5967 AND d.part <> 8)) -- include 5967 but not with part = 8
```

it all works fine except the last line `(c.Id = 5967 AND d.part <> 8), I still see this row in my results. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(c.Id = 5967 AND d.part != 8)`
This should give you just the c.Id=5967 that doesn't contain d.part 8

Comment: The SQL standard not equals operator is `<>`, and it is supported by PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line by

```
AND (c.Id != 5967  OR ( c.id = 5967 AND d.part != 8)))
```